# Magento 2.2.5: Blocks added to footer display in wrong order

Tags: magento2.2, css, static-block, footer, position

I've been working on a magento theme, which inherits from `Magento/blank`, found at http://murkyapparel.com.

As you can see, the footer looks a bit of a mess. I might make some changes, so here is a screenshot for reference:

[image: current footer image]

What I'd like, is something like this:

[image: desired footer image]

Or, this:

[image: another desired footer image]

(Excuse the messy photoshopping... I'm being lazy)

I know that I can use the `before="-"` and `after="-"` attributes to re-arrange the order, but the comodo seal is always placed after the (broken) link to my website and isn't aligned properly.

I've tried editing the `float` and `display` attributes inline, using chrome's code inspector, through each possible combination of `before` and `after` attributes, but I can't find any configuration that will work.

The relevant blocks in my `default.xml` file are as follows:

```
<!-- Add joshuaflood.co.uk link to footer block -->
<referenceBlock name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="jcf-link" template="Magento_Theme::html/jcf_ad_link.phtml" after="-">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string" translate="true">jcf_footer_url</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
<!-- Add Comodo secure seal to footer -->
<referenceBlock name="footer">
    <block class="Magento\Framework\View\Element\Template" name="comodo-secure-seal" template="Magento_Theme::html/secure_seal.phtml" after="footer_links">
        <arguments>
            <argument name="block_id" xsi:type="string" translate="true">comodo_secure_seal</argument>
        </arguments>
    </block>
</referenceBlock>
```

The `jcf_ad_link.phtml` file is currently as follows (tested with all possible options for the `display` option within the `style` attribute, so decided to remove it entirely whilst I (or somebody here) work(s) out the problem):

Website designed by Joshua Flood

The `secure_seal.phtml` looks like this:

```
<div class="secure_seal" style="float: right;">
    <a href="https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate.html" style="text-decoration:none; ">
        <img alt="SSL Certificate" src="https://www.instantssl.com/ssl-certificate-images/support/comodo_secure_100x85_transp.png" style="border: 0px;" />
    </a>
</div>
```

There are no custom CSS styles for either block anywhere else. I know it's not quite magento standard, but I'm planning to convert the majority of my theme's blocks into separate modules so I just want to get the basic layout sorted first and ensure it's all working properly.

The `_extends.less`file within my custom theme contains the following styles for the footer:

```
/* Footer */
.footer.links li {
    display: inline;
}
.footer.links li + li:before {
    content: " | ";
}
div[id^="st-"] .st-btn {
    margin-right: 16px !important;
}
```

There is no other custom styling applied to the footer or elements contained within it.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

replace your less with this update:

```
.footer{
    &.content{
        .links{
            margin-bottom: 20px;
            padding: 0 50px 0 0;
            vertical-align: top;
            float: left; 
        }
        .secure_seal{
            float: right;
        }
        .jcf_ad_link{
            float: none;
            clear: right;
        }
    }
}
```

**Note:** remove your all inline css.

Comment: Accepted and upvoted, because your answer works well. I would like my link list to display inline, though, so I've replaced my existing footer styles within your solution. I also removed all inline styles, which aligned the `.jcf_ad_link` to the left of the site seal, but it was to the left of, not below, the footer links. I've decided to stick with right-alignment because it looks clean enough. Perhaps you could update the question and remove the suggestion to align left, simply advising to remove all inline CSS in order to achieve right-alignment in order to make the answer more accessible.